Issue with Data Display in Table Using ReactJS and antd
My project uses ReactJS and the antd library.
I am facing an issue with displaying data in a table as follows:
Currently, the columns of the table are working correctly, but the rows of the table are not displayed correctly because I am fetching the rows based on the index from a for loop. If the values field of the variants is not consistent, the rows displayed will be incorrect.
Please help me address this issue. Thank you very much!
Here is my code:
Data json:
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Style",
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "variant_id": 1,
            "label": "Hoodie",
            "value": "Hoodie"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "variant_id": 1,
            "label": "Hoodie",
            "value": "Hoodie"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "variant_id": 1,
            "label": "Hoodie",
            "value": "Hoodie"
        },
        {
            "id": 19,
            "variant_id": 1,
            "label": "Hoodie",
            "value": "Hoodie"
        },
        {
            "id": 25,
            "variant_id": 1,
            "label": "Hoodie",
            "value": "Hoodie"
        },
        {
            "id": 31,
            "variant_id": 1,
            "label": "Hoodie",
            "value": "Hoodie"
        },
        {
            "id": 41,
            "variant_id": 1,
            "label": "T-shirt",
            "value": "T-shirt"
        },
        {
            "id": 47,
            "variant_id": 1,
            "label": "T-shirt",
            "value": "T-shirt"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Color",
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "variant_id": 2,
            "label": "Black",
            "value": "#000000"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "variant_id": 2,
            "label": "Black",
            "value": "#000000"
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "variant_id": 2,
            "label": "White",
            "value": "#ffffff"
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "variant_id": 2,
            "label": "White",
            "value": "#ffffff"
        },
        {
            "id": 26,
            "variant_id": 2,
            "label": "Light Pink",
            "value": "#ffb6c1"
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "variant_id": 2,
            "label": "Light Pink",
            "value": "#ffb6c1"
        },
        {
            "id": 42,
            "variant_id": 2,
            "label": "Red",
            "value": "#842b2b"
        },
        {
            "id": 48,
            "variant_id": 2,
            "label": "Red",
            "value": "#842b2b"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Size",
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "variant_id": 3,
            "label": "S",
            "value": "S"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "variant_id": 3,
            "label": "M",
            "value": "M"
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "variant_id": 3,
            "label": "S",
            "value": "S"
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "variant_id": 3,
            "label": "M",
            "value": "M"
        },
        {
            "id": 27,
            "variant_id": 3,
            "label": "S",
            "value": "S"
        },
        {
            "id": 33,
            "variant_id": 3,
            "label": "M",
            "value": "M"
        },
        {
            "id": 43,
            "variant_id": 3,
            "label": "S",
            "value": "S"
        },
        {
            "id": 49,
            "variant_id": 3,
            "label": "M",
            "value": "M"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Price",
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 28,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 34,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 44,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 50,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 54,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 58,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 62,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 66,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 70,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 74,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 78,
            "variant_id": 4,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Sku",
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 29,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 35,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 45,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 51,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 55,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 59,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 63,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 67,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 71,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 75,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        },
        {
            "id": 79,
            "variant_id": 5,
            "label": null,
            "value": null
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Status",
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "0",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 30,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 46,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 52,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 56,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 60,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 64,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 68,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 72,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 76,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 80,
            "variant_id": 6,
            "label": "1",
            "value": "1"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Test",
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 53,
            "variant_id": 7,
            "label": "Value test",
            "value": "Value test"
        },
        {
            "id": 57,
            "variant_id": 7,
            "label": "Value test 2",
            "value": "Value test 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 61,
            "variant_id": 7,
            "label": "Value test 3",
            "value": "Value test 3"
        },
        {
            "id": 77,
            "variant_id": 7,
            "label": "Value test 4",
            "value": "Value test 4"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Test 2",
    "values": [
        {
            "id": 65,
            "variant_id": 8,
            "label": "Test value 22",
            "value": "Test value 22"
        },
        {
            "id": 69,
            "variant_id": 8,
            "label": "Test value 33",
            "value": "Test value 33"
        },
        {
            "id": 73,
            "variant_id": 8,
            "label": "Test value 44",
            "value": "Test value 44"
        }
    ]
}
]

handleVariants() {
    const { action_type, product_id } = this.props;
    const filter = { product_id: product_id };
    const fetchData = action_type === 'create' ? this.props.getListVariantsTmp() : this.props.getListVariants(filter);

    this.setState({ loadingVariantsTemp: true });

    fetchData.then(res => {
        const { data } = res;

        console.log("data", data)

       
        const determineWidth = (name) => {
            switch (name) {
                case 'Price':
                    return 80;
                case 'Sku':
                    return 150;
                default:
                    return 'auto';
            }
        };

       
        const editableColumns = ['Price', 'Sku'];

      
        const newColumns = data.map(variant => ({
            title: variant.name,
            dataIndex: variant.name,
            key: variant.id,
            width: determineWidth(variant.name),
            render: (text, record, index) => {
                
                const valueObject = variant.values[index];

                if (variant.name === 'Color' && valueObject) {
                    const colorCode = variant.values[index].value;
                    return (
                        <>
                            <span style={{ background: colorCode }} className='item-color-variants'>&nbsp;</span>
                            {record[variant.name]} ({colorCode})
                        </>
                    )
                } else if (variant.name === 'Status' && valueObject) {
                    const status = record[variant.name];
                    return (
                        <Switch
                            size="small"
                            defaultChecked={status === '1'}
                            onChange={(value) => this.props.updateVariantsTmp(record[variant.name + '_id'], { value })}
                        />
                    )
                } else {
                    return (
                        <span>{record[variant.name]}</span>
                    )
                }
            },
            onCell: record => ({
                record,
                editable: editableColumns.includes(variant.name),
                dataIndex: variant.name,
                title: variant.name,
                handleSave: this.handleSave,
                handleChange: (value) => this.onChangeItem(variant.name, value, record[variant.name + '_id']),
            }),
        }));

        newColumns.push({
            title: '#',
            key: 'actions',
            width: 40,
            render: (_, record) => (
                <span>
                    <CloseOutlined onClick={() => this.openDeleteVariant(record.ids)} className='item-action-btn-remove' />
                </span>
            ),
        });

        const rowData = [];
        const maxLength = Math.max(...data.map(variant => variant.values.length));

        for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
            const row = {};
            const ids = [];
            data.forEach(variant => {
                const value = variant.values[i];
                if (value) {
                    row[variant.name] = value.label || '';
                    row[`${variant.name}_id`] = value.id;
                    ids.push(value.id);
                } else {
                    row[variant.name] = '';
                    row[`${variant.name}_id`] = '';
                }
            });
            row['ids'] = ids;
            rowData.push(row);
        }
        console.log("rowData", rowData)

        // Cập nhật state
        this.setState({
            variants_columns: newColumns,
            variants_data_source: rowData,
            loadingVariantsTemp: false,
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    });
}

<Table
    rowKey="ids"
    size='small'
    tableLayout='auto'
    rowSelection={rowSelection}
    columns={variants_columns}
    dataSource={variants_data_source}
    pagination={false}
    loading={loadingVariantsTemp}
    rowClassName={() => "editable-row"}
    components={components}
    style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}
    locale={{ emptyText: "No data" }}
   />

Incorrect

Display correctly


In the first line of the input, there are three numbers that show the degree of 3 of the angle that the teacher gave to Ali.
It is guaranteed that all 3 input numbers will be non-negative integers and less than 360.
In the only output line, if we could make a triangle with these 3 angles, print Yes and otherwise, print No.
